# Image upload don't work on WKWebView but works on SFSafariViewController

Tags: android, ios, swift, webview, image-uploading

I'm developing a web app. I'm not the original author, it is legacy code. There's a feature in that app that allows the user to upload an image that is OCRed. It works great in both desktop and mobile.

Now I wrote a simple app in Swift using WKWebView but now when I try to upload an image, WebView is refreshing itself. When I changed WKWebView to SFSafariViewController it works again but SafariVC has this nasty bar on top and bottom.

What are the differences between these two components and how can I make WKWebView run my webapp same like other browsers do?

PS: Android WebView has the same problem.

Comment: It's not possible to answer until you provides details such as chunk of js or swift code.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to enable the `WKWebView`'s JavaScript in the configuration:

```
override fun viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences
    let webview = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    view.addSubview(webview)
}
```

This `WKWebView` creation should be inside a class extending `UIViewController`.